# Extracting Specific Strings From Text

Tags: string, swift

I am trying to extract specific strings from my text. I have a string similar to this:

```
"blablabla(/)Hello Bob(|)bla(/)Hi(|)blablaba"
```

and I am trying to concatenate a string array of text between `(/)` and `(|)` but I cannot figure out a efficient way to do this. In this example I would want to return "Hello Bob" and "Hi". How can I effectively extract specific strings from a string in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a functional approach, you can:

- split the string by `(/)`, which returns an array of strings
- for each element of the array, transform it into an array of strings split by `(|)`
- filter the resulting array including only values (arrays) having more than one element
- transform each element (array) of the resulting array into its first element

This is the code:

```
let array = string.componentsSeparatedByString("(/)")
    .map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString("(|)") }
    .filter { $0.count > 1 }
    .map { $0[0] }
```

Given this input string:

```
let string = "blablabla(/)Hello Bob(|)bla(/)Hi(|)blablaba"
```

the result is:

```
["Hello Bob", "Hi"]
```