# How to Remove Specific Strings Between Identifiers Swift

Tags: swift

If I have have a string like: "blablabla(/)Hello Bob(|)bla(/)Hi(|)blablaba"
and I want to delete all elements between (|) and (/) to produce a string containing "blablablablablablaba" how should i do this in Swift?

Answer (score 3):

You [read the fantastic answer to the previous question that you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26608599/extracting-specific-strings-from-text). Then modify it to fit your new requirements.

Try it in a playground.